# ImageView not displaying after removing

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I have imageView. When i click imageView it display. `I used UIGestureRecognizer` for pan,rotate,longpress. I used `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for removing imageview. After i click the image the imageView is not displaying.

code:

```
-(void)img:(id)sender {
    [self.view addSubView:myImageView];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *sslongpress=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sslongPress:)];
    [myImageView addGestureRecognizer:sslongpress];
}

-(void)sslongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    [myImageView removeFromSuperview];    
}
```

Comment: I used button for call img method

Comment: Check if `myImageView = nil`? How do you create `myImageView`? Do you use ARC or manual memory management?

Comment: Can you post code of how you declare and initialize `myImageView`?

Comment: did you enable the interaction for your image view? If not, enable it. Another solution is, hide your view when you don't need to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**removeFromSuperview** property remove view in super view not move in view,use below code to move your view using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

```
-(void)sslongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:view_.superview];

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
      //  myImageView.hidden=NO;
        myImageView.center=point;
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        myImageView.center=point;
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        //myImageView.hidden=YES;
        myImageView.center=point;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to set myImageView? First i click, i need to remove. After i click i need to add myImageView to view.

Comment: you add image view in view use hidden property show uiimageview in super view

Answer (score 0):

try this:

use minimumPressDuration property of UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

```
sslongpress.minimumPressDuration = _____ ; //_____ = your value
```

and also see the more detail for minimumPressDuration property on [UILongPressGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) developer.apple.com

Comment: minimumPressDuration is only optional in ios, Default is 0.5. Time in seconds the fingers must be held down for the gesture to be recognized